# Google Apps Scipt - Using OnEdit to transpose data from input

Tags: function, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm new to GAS and am struggling with the OnEdit function to copy and paste data from one sheet to another. I have an input sheet and a master sheet that use OnEdit to read "Submit" from cell D36 and transfer data from `"Input" E3:E36` to `"MasterList" A5:AG5` as a transpose.

My code (see below) simply deletes all data from the input sheet once "Submit" is selected in the dropdown list. Nothing is showing up on the "MasterList" sheet. Is the selected range getting deleted in this code, and if so how can I ensure that it's pasted in the "MasterList" sheet at the end of the last row of data (shown as row 5 here)?

Is there also a way to retain the formulas from the Input range for future input (I have a vlookup in E8:E10 based off of data entered in E5)?

```
function onEdit(e) {

if (e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() !== "Input" || e.range.rowStart != 36 || e.range.columnStart != 4 | e.value !== "Submit") return
e.source.getActiveSheet()
.getRange("E3:E36")
    .setValue(e.source.getSheetByName("MasterList")
        .getRange("A5:AG5")
        .getValue())

}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The commands setValue and getValue are for one cell ranges or at most the upper left corner cell of a large range.  If you want to get values from multicell ranges use getValues which returns a 2 dimensional array of values and if you want to set values for multicell ranges then use setValues here's a [resource link](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range) which describes the functions along with some examples.

Also when you're creating new code it's easier to debug if you'll break up  your command chains so that you can look at the intermediate answers with the debugger.

Comment: Thanks for the response, Cooper. When I went and updated getValues and setValues in this code, nothing happens on either the input or master sheet. Is this because the selected range cannot be parsed as a 2 dimensional array?

Comment: This has been a source of difficulties for me as well. In fact I did some testing with single rows and single columns and multiple rows and columns just to learn a bit more about the problems and how to solve them by using the debugger I've been able to develop a picture in my head which helps me to visualize and remedy these problems.  I wrote a little about it and did a short video that you can find [here](https://sites.google.com/view/googlappsscript/javascript-array-difficulties) I think it might help you to understand how to deal with this issue.